# Connect-MsolService : The term 'Connect-MsolService' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,

Tags: windows, powershell

A lot of people have posted this problem before, and I have tried all their solutions, but none of them work.

It used to work on both mac and windows (in parallels), but now it works on neither with the above errors.

This post is regarding windows 11 (in parallels).  Im running power shell (the default one), as administrator.

Ive downloaded and installed the sharepoint shell from here:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35588

First thing I tried was this:

`Install-Module –Name PowerShellGet –Force`

This runs without error.

Next:

`Update-Module -Name PowerShellGet`

Then:

`Install-Module -Name MSOnline`

After this when I run MSOnline, I get:

```
Connect-MsolService : The term 'Connect-MsolService' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,  or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Connect-MsolService
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Connect-MsolService:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I tried the following also:

Install-Module AzureAD
Import-Module AzureAD
uninstall-module AzureAD
install-module AzureAD
install-module AzureADPreview

Which didnt help.

If I do :

`Import-Module MSOnline`

I get:

```
Import-Module : Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\MSOnline\1.1.183.66\Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.PSModule.dll' 
or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

Ive also tried running the (x64) version of power shell as administrator, which a) gives the same errors, and b) gives the "PS C:\Windows\System32>" prompt implying its not 64 bit?  The "normal" version of power shell (with no (xyy) ending) gives prompt of "PS C:\Users\me>"

After spending many days trying to solve this, now when I run power shell it always says "do you want to run this from an unknown publisher" or similar, which is pretty strange as Microsoft is not that unknown.

Comment: Try -Force option https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/powershellget/install-module?view=powershellget-2.x#description